# Laravel sidebar template

Tags: php, laravel, sidebar

I want to make a sidebar for my webpage but I am having some trouble doing it, I followed a lot of tutorial and yet the sidebar didn't come out instead only the words came out. Most people I saw just only use php but I feel like there is a need to use javascript. Can someone give me a template on making a sidebar something like this in the screenshot.

[image]

This is the codes that I used:
sidebar.blade.php

```
 <div class="app-body">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <nav class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="main.html"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Dashboard <span class="badge badge-primary">NEW</span></a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-title">
            UI Elements
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-puzzle"></i> Components</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="components/buttons.html"><i class="icon-puzzle"></i> Buttons</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="components/social-buttons.html"><i class="icon-puzzle"></i> Social Buttons</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-star"></i> Icons</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="icons/font-awesome.html"><i class="icon-star"></i> Font Awesome <span class="badge badge-secondary">4.7</span></a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="widgets.html"><i class="icon-calculator"></i> Widgets <span class="badge badge-primary">NEW</span></a>
          </li>

            Extras
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-star"></i> Pages</a>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="views/pages/login.html" target="_top"><i class="icon-star"></i> Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="views/pages/register.html" target="_top"><i class="icon-star"></i> Register</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <button class="sidebar-minimizer brand-minimizer" type="button"></button>
    </div>
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to implement adminLTE template for admin panel as you showed in your screenshot?

Comment: @HirenGohel I was just using that as an example but it ok, I found another solution tks for your help

Comment: Ok, no problem! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using any admin templates? https://colorlib.com/wp/free-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-templates/

Comment: Yup, I just found the link also, tks for your help, I had used this http://coreui.io/demo/Ajax_Demo/#main.html, probably because I google the wrong keywords

Comment: I think you are missing some component both JS & CSS in that template.

Comment: Yup, I found another example and it contain some JS which help solved my problem tks a lot for your help @Nyicip